# Add text to a button with an icon

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a button with the Feedback Hub icon (Segoe MDL2 Assets), and I wanted to add the text: "Feedback", after the icon, but since I already have the icon it is possible to add the text?
Here is an example of my button:

`<Button x:Name="feedbackButton" 
         FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
         Content="&#xE939;" 
         Click="feedbackButton_Click"/>`

I try: `Content="&#xE939; Feedback";`, but the word "Feedback" dont appears!

Comment: posible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191758/uwp-xaml-how-to-display-a-button-with-icon-and-text-in-it)

Comment: This example does not solve my problem, because I want an icon (via textblock) + text in the button. I do not want a image + text in the button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP xaml: How to display a button with icon and text in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191758/uwp-xaml-how-to-display-a-button-with-icon-and-text-in-it)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try putting the icon text and text in separate `Run`s of a `TextBlock` like this -

```
<Button>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="&#xE939;"
             FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />
        <Run Text="Feedback" />
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

### Update

Isn't this what the OP wanted? Why the downvote??

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I want!

Comment: @JustinXL Excellent response. Worked even on my `WPF` app on Windows 10. Deserves an upvote. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

You can place a *StackPanel* inside your *Button* and then add as many *TextBlocks* into your *StackPanel* as you need:

```
   <Button x:Name="feedbackButton" Click="feedbackButton_Click">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="&#xE939;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Feedback" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

Comment: StackPanel is really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Button is a ContentControl. Its XAML content property is Content, which enables a syntax like this for XAML: A button's content. You can set any object as the button's content. If the content is a UIElement, it is rendered in the button. If the content is another type of object, its string representation is shown in the button.
Here, a StackPanel that contains an image of an orange and text is set as the content of a button.3

```
<Button>
   <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
            Text="&#xE939;" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Feedback" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
   </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

I change the code. I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! But this example does not solve my problem, because I want an icon (via textblock - Segoe MDL2 Assets) + text in the button. I do not want a image + text in the button

Comment: StackPanel is really necessary?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. StackPanel is not really necessary. Based on the information I gathered, "The StackPanel in WPF is a simple and useful layout panel. It stacks its child elements below or beside each other, dependening on its orientation. This is very useful to create any kinds of lists."

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

- Define a custom control `ButtonWithIcon`:

  ```
  public class ButtonWithIcon : Button
  {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty IconContentProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("IconContent", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonWithIcon), new PropertyMetadata(default(Icon)));

      public string IconContent
      {
          get => (string)GetValue(IconContentProperty);
          set => SetValue(IconContentProperty, value);
      }
  }
  ```

In particular I added a `DependencyProperty` to enable a specific binding for the icon code.

- Then, I would define the style for that control in `App.xaml`:

  ```
  <Style x:Key="buttonWithIconStyle" TargetType="customControls:ButtonWithIcon">
      <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#cccccc" />
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
      <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#333333" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="16,3,16,3" />
      <Setter Property="Template">

          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type customControls:ButtonWithIcon}">
                  <Border
                      Name="Chrome"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="true">

                      <StackPanel
                          Margin="8,0"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Orientation="Vertical">

                          <TextBlock
                              x:Name="Icon"
                              Foreground="White"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
                              Text="{Binding IconContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                          <TextBlock
                              x:Name="Text"
                              Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                              FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
                              FontSize="10"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              Foreground="White" />

                      </StackPanel>

                  </Border>

                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                      </Trigger>
                      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                          <Setter Property="Background" Value="#000000" />
                          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#cccccc" />
                          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                      </Trigger>
                      <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                          <Setter Property="Background" Value="#999999" />
                          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MainColor}" />
                          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                      </Trigger>
                      <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                          <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MainColor}" />
                      </Trigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
  </Style>
  ```

In particular I added a `StackPanel` to contain the `Content` property with plain text and the `IconContent` property with the code of the icon.

- At the end, you can use it like this:

  ```
  <customControls:ButtonWithIcon
      Style="{StaticResource "buttonWithIconStyle"}"
      IconContent="&#xE14C;"
      Content="Some text" />
  ```
- Remember to reference the custom control in your Window's references:

  ```
  xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:MyProjectNamespace.Controls"
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's needed so much code just to put a button with an icon and text?

Comment: I'm not sure, I didn't find a less-code solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inbuilt https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AppBarButton AppBarButton control or use its style.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! That's not what I'm looking for, but it's a great alternative!